# Undefined pdfannot in beamer when using lualatex - multimedia

Tags: beamer, luatex, multimedia

I have the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt, 
    no-math,
    ]{beamer}
\usepackage{multimedia}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \movie[width=300pt,height=240pt,poster]{}{whatsapp.mp4}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

When using `pdflatex`, it compiles. (I can't see the movie, but that's probably due to my not using Adobe Reader).

However, when using `lualatex`, which I **need** to use, I get an undefined error:

```
./main.tex:8: Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \pdfannot 
          width \@tempdima height \@tempdimb depth \@tempdimc { /Subtype /Movie
l.8 \end{frame}
```

Is it possible to run around this, and if so, how?

Comment: `\RequirePackage{luatex85}`

Comment: @UlrikeFischer would you add it as answer or do I delete que question?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because solved in comments

Comment: Well it saved my day (though I do not understand why the same documents used to compile fine without this line before...)